# Redirect to an Action in MVC with popup countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an existing mvc3 application that I am adding more to.  I would like to post information in one view and have the app come to a summary page, have a dialog of some sort with a countdown to 0 and if the user doesn't "submit" the form after say 25 seconds, to auto-redirect to an action in my controller..

I can get the refresh to the action to happen using this line at the top of my summary view.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="25;URL=@(Url.Action("CancelandLogoff", "Account"))" />
```

but I would like the popup as well ..

Can someone give me a clue how to do this?

Thanks! 
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use javascript & jQuery at your view.
This is some kind you can do:

Put the below element at where you want:

```
<div id="dCountDown"></div>
```

The below is javascript:

```
var countDownVal = 25;
$('#dCountDown').html(countDownVal);
var timer1 = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer()
{
   countDownVal--;
   $('#dCountDown').html(countDownVal);
   if (countDownVal == 0)
   {
      clearInterval(timer1); // this thing can be here, or not, it's OK
      window.location.replace("/CancelandLogoff/Account"); // or whatever address you want
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.
-Han-

Comment: This definitely worked... the only thing I would say is... Is there a way to stop the countdown once the form is submitting so it won't keep counting ?

Comment: The call `clearInterval(timer1)` will stop timer `timer1`. It won't continue counting down. Or you can put an `if (countDownVal <= 0) return;` statement inside top of `function myTimer()`

Comment: Or you want to stop timer when user is submitting the form, let call `clearInterval(timer1)` in onsubmit event of the form. Regards!